# How do I position one image on top of another in HTML

Tags: html, css, image

How to do this in HTML/CSS? (Please check the image)

[image on top of an another image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdnF3.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This is not a code writing service, - it is expected that you have researched your issue and made a good attempt to write the code yourself. If you get stuck on something specific, come back and include a summary of what you have tried and the relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can help.

Comment: Why don't you look at that page's HTML and CSS and find out how they did it?

Comment: The best thing about HTML+CSS is everyone has their source available for inspection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I did for my website (it's barely changed from the actual code, so there's a lot of useless stuff in the CSS.) All you need to do is copy/paste this text and insert your image's URL.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <style>
.div1{
 border-style: hidden;
 background-image: url("yourImage.jpg");
 background-color: red;
 background-size: 100% 100%;
 position: absolute;
 right: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 top: 10%;
 z-index: -2;
 padding: 10%;
 margin:0px;
}
.div2{
 position: relative;
 top: 50%;
 background-color: rgba(153,194,255,0.8);
 z-index: 1;
 padding-right: 50px;
 padding-left: 50px;
 height:300px;
 width: 60%;
 min-width: 300px;
 margin: auto;
}

.myText{
 margin: auto;
 padding: 50px;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 1.5em;
 font-family: Verdana,sans-serif;
 width: 80%;
 height: 100%;
}
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="div1"> 
 <div class="div2"><p class="myText">hey</p></div>
 </div>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Next time, maybe do a little bit more research, but hey... everybody is lazy once in a while, right!?